# Send an email in SuiteScript 1.0 using email template?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitecommerce

When sending an email using `nlapiSendEmail()` can I specify a email template to use?

I have created an email template in the NetSuite backend. Is there a function I can use to send an email and use that email template?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `nlapiCreateEmailMerger(templateId)` to get the body and subject of the email:

```
var emailMerger = nlapiCreateEmailMerger(templateId);

var mergeResult = emailMerger.merge();
var body = mergeResult.getBody();
var subject = mergeResult.getSubject();

nlapiSendEmail(author, recipient, subject, body, null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

I do mine like this:

```
var emailSendID='xxxx'; // Email author ID
var emailTempID=123;    // Template ID
var emailTemp=nlapiLoadRecord('emailtemplate',emailTempID); 
var emailSubj=emailTemp.getFieldValue('subject');
var emailBody=emailTemp.getFieldValue('content');

var renderer=nlapiCreateTemplateRenderer();
renderer.setTemplate(emailSubj);
renderSubj=renderer.renderToString();
renderer.setTemplate(emailBody);
renderBody=renderer.renderToString();

nlapiSendEmail(emailSendID,'noreply@xxxxx',renderSubj,renderBody,finalEmailArray,bccEmailArray);
```

Comment: thanks this really helps. How can I add custom text to the template? For example; the template is for 'Contact us' so theres the general template/look of the email then I need to insert the contact us details such as the persons name, phone and message. Is there a way to insert that into the template body (`emailTemp.getFieldValue('content')`)?

Comment: I have not tried that.  Though, you can create variables in the template, that pull from the records.  You may be able to use those to link data into the template.